# Django 1.10 raises error when installing fixtures: no such column: REFERRED.id

Tags: json, django-admin, loaddata

I created a fixture with this command:

```
python manage.py dumpdata --natural-primary --natural-foreign -e admin -e contenttypes -e auth.Permission --format=json --indent=2 --all > gc_core/fixtures/initial_data.json
```

Then I tried to test it on my other machine. So I deleted my database and run migrations there:

```
./manage.py migrate
```

Then I tried to populate my database with that fixture using loaddata:

```
./manage.py loaddata gc_core/fixtures/initial_data.json
```

Then Django raises this error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: Problem installing fixtures: no such column: REFERRED.id
```

I have no idea what this means. Should I have a column somewhere named REFERRED.id?

There is no such column in my fixture nor in the database and I didn't defined such model in any of my apps.

So what is REFERRED.id and how do I fix it?

I'm using **Django 1.10**, **Python 3.5.2**, **SQLite**. The fixture I'm trying to load is in **JSON** format.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this question when I encountered the same issue.

Here is a possible answer that is likely just a theory but I will explain why.

Django is having trouble loading relationships with primary keys that are not auto indexes on SQLite databases.

I am encountering this issue because the test database strategy we employ is by using an SQLite database instead of the production like Postgres database. I have been breaking my head over the exact same error all day. When I switched to Postgres for the test database as well, it ended up not being an issue. There might be a bigger problem at large here. Hopefully someone else can provide a more clear answer.

I am using the same version of Django and Python 2.7

If possible, could you try moving the data into a Postgres equivalent and load it. If that does work, it means your data is not wrong, and the relationship SQLite and Django is having issues.